# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS scripts in /if-up.d not executed

Tags: 12.04, networking, mount, scripts

Since this morning have been trying to achieve something:

**System:**
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Network-Manager is not installed

**Goal:**
Every time, the `eth0` network interface is started (`if-up.d`) we want to unmount and remount some external sources (different machine).

**Things I tried:**

- Mount in `rc.local` (doesn't work)
- Mount automatically when interfaces are up (`if-up.d`, doesn't work)
- Mount explicitly through `/etc/network/interfaces` with post-up at the
  end of the `eth0` configuration (doesn't work)

**Problem:**

- It seems that the scripts in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` are not even
  executed
- It seems the post-up command in `/etc/network/interfaces` is ignored
- We are not able to mount the external directory after computer
  restart / network restart

**Additional information:**

- `/etc/network/interfaces` contains `eth0` interface.
- `eth0` connection is automatically started
- `eth0` is a static interface
- post-up `{FULL_PATH_TO_SCRIPT}/[un]mount-vcomhub01` is not executed
  either
- The two scripts `mount-vcomhub01` and `unmount-vcomhub01` are valid, no
  problem with execution. The mount is successfully mounted when
  running this script.
- The two scripts are in the correct format (executable, without `.sh` ending)
- `/etc/network/run/ifstate` does not contain eth0=eth0 even though the connection is established

Does anybody have an idea what could be the problem and what else we could try?

Comment: You mean static as in "Static IP", no DHCP?  If yes, is it extremely difficult to test it with DHCP? (Like: this is not a DHCP server)